# Building riot/helloworld with Docker

Tags: docker, riot-os

This is my setup:

1. `docker pull riot/riotbuild`
2. `wget https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/archive/2019.04.zip`
3. `unzip 2019.04.zip`
4. `cd RIOT-2019.04/examples/hello-world/`
5. `make BUILD_IN_DOCKER=1 BOARD=stm32f4discovery all`

   All of this is OK.
6. `make BUILD_IN_DOCKER=1 BOARD=stm32f4discovery flash`

   This step failed. Error is :

```
>   Building application "hello-world" for "stm32f4discovery" with MCU
> "stm32f4". "make" -C /data/riotbuild/riotbase/boards/stm32f4discovery
> "make" -C /data/riotbuild/riotbase/core "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu/stm32f4 "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu/cortexm_common "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu/cortexm_common/periph "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu/stm32_common "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu/stm32_common/periph "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu/stm32f4/periph "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/drivers "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/drivers/periph_common "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys/auto_init "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys/isrpipe "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys/newlib_syscalls_default "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys/pm_layered "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys/stdio_uart "make" -C
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/sys/tsrb    text    data     bss     dec    
> hex filename    8756     140    2620   11516    2cfc
> /data/riotbuild/riotbase/examples/hello-world/bin/stm32f4discovery/hello-world.elf
> /home/huaxing/oproj/riot/RIOT-2019.04/dist/tools/openocd/openocd.sh
> flash
> /home/huaxing/oproj/riot/RIOT-2019.04/examples/hello-world/bin/stm32f4discovery/hello-world.elf
> Flashing Target  sh: 1: openocd: not found
> /home/huaxing/oproj/riot/RIOT-2019.04/examples/hello-world/../../Makefile.include:538:
> recipe for target 'flash' failed make: *** [flash] Error 127
```

Comment: Step2 ~ Step6 in container?

Comment: all not in container

Answer (score 0):

I check the script, in fact it will finally call docker as next:

**a) make BUILD_IN_DOCKER=1 BOARD=stm32f4discovery all**

```
docker run --rm -t -u "$(id -u)" \
-v '/usr/share/zoneinfo/PRC:/etc/localtime:ro' -v '/home/shubuntu1/g/RIOT-2019.04:/data/riotbuild/riotbase' -e 'RIOTBASE=/data/riotbuild/riotbase' -e 'CCACHE_BASEDIR=/data/riotbuild/riotbase' -e 'BUILD_DIR=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/build' -e 'RIOTPROJECT=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/examples/hello-world' -e 'RIOTCPU=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu' -e 'RIOTBOARD=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/boards' -e 'RIOTMAKE=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/makefiles'     \
-e 'BOARD=stm32f4discovery' \
-w '/data/riotbuild/riotbase/examples/hello-world/' \
'riot/riotbuild:latest' make all 'BOARD=stm32f4discovery'
```

**b) make BUILD_IN_DOCKER=1 BOARD=stm32f4discovery flash**

```
docker run --rm -t -u "$(id -u)" \
-v '/usr/share/zoneinfo/PRC:/etc/localtime:ro' -v '/home/shubuntu1/g/RIOT-2019.04:/data/riotbuild/riotbase' -e 'RIOTBASE=/data/riotbuild/riotbase' -e 'CCACHE_BASEDIR=/data/riotbuild/riotbase' -e 'BUILD_DIR=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/build' -e 'RIOTPROJECT=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/examples/hello-world' -e 'RIOTCPU=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/cpu' -e 'RIOTBOARD=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/boards' -e 'RIOTMAKE=/data/riotbuild/riotbase/makefiles'     \
-e 'BOARD=stm32f4discovery' \
-w '/data/riotbuild/riotbase/examples/hello-world/' \
'riot/riotbuild:latest' make  'BOARD=stm32f4discovery'
```

They are nearly same, and the main use for container is just to build the source to stm32 binary as it's not add any permissions to control hardware when start container.

Compare to `a)`, the `b)` also have next output:

> ### Flashing Target ###
>   sh: 1: openocd: not found
>   /home/shubuntu1/g/RIOT-2019.04/examples/hello-world/../../
> Makefile.include:538: recipe for target 'flash' failed
>   make: *** [flash] Error 127

This in fact not related to container, it runs on host, the root cause is you do not install `openocd` on host which used to flash the stm32 binary to device.

See [this](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/Tutorials/blob/master/README.md), search `OpenOCD`, it clear requires you to install openocd, then after the docker container finish the build, the binary will also be in host as it's in docker volume, and finally the `openocd` on host could flash your binary.